# JQuery - placing the cursor at the end of a textarea when it is focused on

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

First, some of you may notice that I reposted this question after deleting it. This is because it was mistakenly marked as a duplicate by someone who didn't bother to check - the question he linked to was about an `<input>` element; that solution does not work for textareas.

Anyway, consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function caek() {
    $('textarea[name=txt1]').val("cake");
    $('textarea[name=txt1]').focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar"></div>
<form name="frm1" id="cake">
<textarea name="txt1"></textarea>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Activate"
onclick="caek()">
</body>
</html>
```

When you run that, you will notice that the cursor is pushed to the start of the textarea, before the text. How can I make it come *after* all the text, at the end of the textarea? A non-inline solution would be optimal, but anything will do.

And a standalone solution (no plugins etc) would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
function caek() {
    txtArea = $('textarea[name=txt1]');
    txtArea.val("cake");
    txtArea.focus();    
    tmpStr = txtArea.val();
    txtArea.val('');
    txtArea.val(tmpStr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
$ta.text($ta.text()).focus()
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/WWsBa/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [rangyinputs](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) jQuery plugin to do this in a cross platform way.

There's a demo here:

http://rangyinputs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textinputs_jquery.html

Set the start and end to the same number and it'll set the cursor to that point (though it doesn't focus the textarea, so you have to tab into it to see the effect). In your case, you'd want to set it to the length of the text.

Comment: The site says a standalone version is coming at some point. But it's open source, so you can probably just yank out the code you want. :)